# Python3 CGI-Script Environment encoding fedora

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, fedora

I have a problem with a CGI script in Python3. When I try to open files to write a file name with German special characters like `Ä` or `Ö`, I always get an error message because of the encoding. 
The output of `locale.getpreferredencoding()).name` is `ASCII` but I want `UTF-8`. How can I switch this to `UTF-8`? Do I have to change the apache configuration? It is running fine on my Mac but not on the Linux machine. How do I do this in fedora24? The module `mod_env` is loaded. The Variable `LANG` is also set to `en_US.utf-8`.

I tried this:

```
out = open('files/' + name , 'wb', _block_size)
```

`name` is an UTF-8 encoded string. And I get this error message:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's because there is an "ä" -character in the filename.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and add the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: I try this : out = open('files/' + name , 'wb', _block_size). name is UTF-8 encoded string. and i get this error message :'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128). its beacause the is an "ä" -character in the filename

Comment: For future reference, please edit your question, if you have additional information. You can't format code properly in comments, but in your question you have the {} button to do this. Also, many people don't read comments, hence ask the same question again. I have done this for you now.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not add path with `+`, but with `os.path.join()`.

Encoding pathnames is different to text encoding: it is not just a encoding format, but it is also relevant to OS). So finally, starting from Python 3.2, we have support for such encoding: we have `os.fsencode()` (before 3.2, one should convert manually into bytestrings):

```
out = open(os.fsencode('files/' + name), 'wb', _block_size)
```

Personally I would do a `open(os.path.join('files', os.fsencode(name)), ...)`, but this is supported only from Python 3.6 (before that, put `os.fsencode` outside `os.path.join`.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo for this tipp, but i still have the default encoding ASCII in my CGI script .....and i like to have UTF-8

Comment: set the locale, e.g. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8'`. But  1: filename are "outside" locales (different filesystems use different encodings). 2: your webserver and your "CGI" like communication should be correctly set.

Comment: Solved the problem...i had some strange packages installed in Python3.5.2. Installed 3.6.2 without that packages because they where unnessesary and it worked

Comment: If you write what package caused the problem, you could help other users.

Comment: Yes the package name was "envparse"